# In krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker how I can set check-in and check-out dates programmatically?

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a vue js project in which I'm using vue-hotel-datepicker for date range selection. But how I can to change/set the date range programmatically?
For example, the user selected this [example date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAJL5.png). And I want to change the range by adding 1 more day in check-in date programmatically. How I can do this change? There're no such props available in the document as well which I can use to set check-in and check-out dates programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

a little late but

```
<template> <HotelDatePicker ref="hoteldatesform" /></template>

 methods: { setHotelDatePicker(){
  this.$refs.hoteldatesform.checkIn = new Date("2021-02-04");
  this.$refs.hoteldatesform.checkOut = new Date("2021-02-09");}}
```